# Success to insert data in OneToMany Relationship, but then failed to insert data due to ConstraintViolationException after wait for some time

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I tried to insert data on delivery model by click button on requestUpdateItem HTML. First, it works, and after some time, for reason that I don't know, somehow it failed and give me this error.

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

at apap.tugasakhir.sifactory.service.DeliveryServiceImpl.addDelivery(DeliveryServiceImpl.java:35)
at apap.tugasakhir.sifactory.service.DeliveryServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ef9321f.invoke(<generated>)

at apap.tugasakhir.sifactory.service.DeliveryServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9dac215c.addDelivery(<generated>)
at apap.tugasakhir.sifactory.controller.DeliveryController.tambahDeliverySubmit(DeliveryController.java:159)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sifactory`.`delivery`, CONSTRAINT `FK4ah2rannygixep2r1bp3owkby` FOREIGN KEY (`id_delivery`) REFERENCES `pegawai` (`id_pegawai`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Here is my code for DeliveryModel and PegawaiModel

```
@Table(name = "delivery")
public class DeliveryModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_delivery;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_cabang", nullable = false)
    private Integer idCabang;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tanggal_dibuat", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate tanggal_dibuat;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tanggal_dikirim", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate tanggal_dikirim;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sent", nullable = false)
    private Boolean sent;

    //Many to One Relationship ke Pegawai
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pegawai", referencedColumnName = "id_pegawai")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private PegawaiModel idKurir;

    //One to One Relationship ke Request Update Item
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_request_update_item", referencedColumnName = "id_request_update_item")
    @JsonIgnore
    private RequestUpdateItemModel id_request_update_item;
}
```

and for PegawaiModel

```
public class PegawaiModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_pegawai;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "nama", nullable = false)
    private String nama;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="tanggal_lahir", nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date tanggalLahir;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_role", referencedColumnName = "id_role", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private RoleModel id_role;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "counter", nullable = false)
    private Integer counter;

    //One to many relationship ke DeliveryModel
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_delivery", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<DeliveryModel> listDelivery;

    //One to many relationship ke ProduksiModel
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_pegawai", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ProduksiModel> listProduksi;


}
```

and this is my DeliveryController

```
@PostMapping("/delivery/add/{idRUI}")
    public String tambahDeliverySubmit(@ModelAttribute DeliveryModel delivery, Model model, @PathVariable Integer idRUI) {
        RequestUpdateItemModel rui = requestUpdateItemService.getRequestUpdateItemById(idRUI);

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = (User)auth.getPrincipal();
        String username = user.getUsername();

        PegawaiModel pegawai = pegawaiService.getUserByUsername(username);

        if (rui.getDelivery() == null) {
            pegawai.setCounter(pegawai.getCounter()+1);
            List<DeliveryModel> listDelivery = pegawai.getListDelivery();
            listDelivery.add(delivery);
            pegawai.setListDelivery(listDelivery);
            pegawaiService.updatePegawai(pegawai);

            deliveryService.addDelivery(delivery);

            rui.setExecuted(false);
            rui.setDelivery(delivery);
            requestUpdateItemService.updateRequestUpdateItem(rui);

            delivery.setId_request_update_item(rui);
            deliveryService.updateDelivery(delivery);

            model.addAttribute("idRequest", delivery.getId_request_update_item().getId_request_update_item());
            return "add-delivery";
        } else {
            return "delivery-failed";
        }
    }
```

What I confused most is when I tried in local, it worked. After some time, it gets that error. I tried to drop the DB, and it worked again. But after some time, it gets that error again. I also confuse why the error is on relationship between Delivery and Pegawai, because if I print delivery.getIdKurir(), it prints the right kurir (driver).

I want to push this project on to heroku, but there is also give me this error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
```

I am stuck. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I see, there is a problem in your PegawaiModel. You have addressed 'mappedBy = "id_delivery"' for field listDelivery, while you had to declare the name of the corresponding field in the other model, namely 'idKurir'. You must modify it into this:

```
//One to many relationship ke DeliveryModel
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idKurir", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private List<DeliveryModel> listDelivery;
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. I have tried it. For additional info, when I tried to insert data via PHPMyAdmin, it didn't work too. I don't get it why it happen